# Select by attributes for Arabic fonts in SDE/ file geodatabases?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-spatial, internationalization, arabic

I have a layer with names of electrical substations in Arabic language.  there is no any problem when searching any Field names in English language whether from the SDE of file goedatabase
I got the same feature class in SDE and file geodatabase. Searching the Arabic names in file geodatabase works very well and has no problem. Searching the Arabic names from the SDE geodatabase has a problem. It doesn't recognize Arabic languages and thus ends up finding nothing.
I am using Arcgis desktop 10.2.1 with arcfm 10.2.1a and Oracle 11G

What might be the issue here?

[image]

Comment: what is the charset of your oracle database?

Comment: American america ar8mswin 1256

Comment: It's Oracle, not ArcGIS, which does not recognize the characters.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to create a new database with "AL32UTF8" charset in oracle database; Then import your data into it. If worked fine then drop your existing database. Most of the problems with finding text attributes is from dbms charset.